# Is it possible to show line number in side-by-side diff output?

Tags: diff

I am using diff with the `-y` and `--suppress-common-lines` options and the output is almost perfect except I'd like to see the line numbers of the changes.

Example:

file1:

```
line a
line b
line c
```

file2:

```
line a
line B
line c
line d
```

command and output:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2
line b                                                        | line B
                                                              > line d
```

Is this combination of options possible with diff or do I need another tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the `-y` option uses the formatting style internally (as does `--LFMT-line-format`), you cannot cumulate formatting commands with `-y`.
You cannot obtain from formatting parameters what `-y` does, so you cannot workaround directly with `diff` (I checked diff 3.2 source code).

You need to use another tool.

Comment: I was fairly sure of this but thank you for confirming! Now to find another tool...

Answer (score 0):

If you are always comparing lines with the same line numbers, you can use something like this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{x=a[FNR];if($0!=x)printf("%s;%s;%s\n",FNR,x,$0)}' file1 file2
327;有る;ある
431;先ず;まず
543;連れて行く;連れていく
719;幾ら;いくら
1318;込む;混む
1415;かわいそう;可哀相
1713;だんだん;段々
2491;大みそか;大晦日
4120;もうける;儲ける
4510;ほほ笑む;微笑む
4512;もうかる;儲かる
5727;剥げる;剝げる
```

`FNR` (file number of record) is equal to `NR` when awk is processing the first file. The `next` statement skips to the next record.